# Insert user register into my own user table instead of wp own user

Tags: users, forms, wpdb, user-registration

I have found this register form on http://www.sutanaryan.com/2011/12/wordpress-custom-registration-without-using-a-plugin/ but in this case it is registering into wordpress own user table. What i would like to do is to insert into my own table for userclients

THIS IS WHAT I'VE FOUND ONLINE:

```
global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;

$user_id = wp_insert_user( array (
'first_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name), 
'last_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name), 
'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 
'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 
'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email)
) 
);
        if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $err = 'Error on user creation.';
        } else {
            do_action('user_register', $user_id);

            $success = 'You\'re successfully register';
        }
```

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

```
global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;

$user_id = wpdb->INSERT INTO( 'wp_fisker' array 
(
'fisker_fornavn' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $fisker_fornavn),
'fisker_efternavn' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name',$fisker_efternavn),
'password' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $password),
'telefon' => apply_filters('pre_user_telefon', $telefon),
'zip' => apply_filters('pre_user_zip', $zip),
'by_navn' => apply_filters('pre_user_by_navn', $by_navn),
'email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 
'role' => 'subscriber' 
) 
        );
        if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $err = 'Error on user creation.';
        } else {
            do_action('user_register', $user_id);

            $success = 'You\'re successfully register';
        }
```

I'm getting an error of a unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

I hope you can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself I needed $wpdb and a , after the db_name Here is the result.

```
        $user_id = $wpdb->INSERT( 
            'wp_fisker',
            array (
            'fisker_fornavn' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $fisker_fornavn),
            'fisker_efternavn' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $fisker_efternavn),
            'password' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $password),
            'telefon' => apply_filters('pre_user_telefon', $telefon),
            'zip' => apply_filters('pre_user_zip', $zip),
            'by_navn' => apply_filters('pre_user_by_navn', $by_navn),
            'email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email) 
            )
        );
        if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $err = 'Error on user creation.';
        } else {
            do_action('user_register', $user_id);

            $success = 'You\'re successfully register';
        }
```